# Is it necessary to uninstall an app before pushing it on to the device via ADB, to ensure it is up to date?

Tags: android, adb

I am currently developing an application and testing it on my Android device.  When I make changes to it, is it necessary to uninstall it from my device before pushing it on there via ADB?  Or, when pushing it on the device, does it completely replace the old version?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to uninstall if you built it with a different certificate. One example: if you installed it from Google Play (where you had to digitally sign it for upload) and now you're trying to run it from Eclipse (without signing it) it will ask you to uninstall it first from the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No its not necessary** to uninstall application! it replaces old application ! if your ADB is pushing and replacing the existing app, than it does not completely removes the app data, but if you manually uninstall the app then it is completely removed !

Comment: Though is it possible that the old app data could interfere with the new version?

Comment: Yeah, depending on the change you may need to clear data or uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

It replaces the old one. You can see it in the console log.

Answer (score 1):

No. When you run the program, the emulator will automatically replace. You can also view the app activity in Console. See the image i have attached. You can also clear the app data before running by going to Setting-> Manage application -> Clear.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**No need to uninstall** if your command is like `adb install -r app.apk` (parameter -r replace current app with new one).

P.S. **You need to uninstall it ONLY** when you got your old appication without the certificate and try to install the new one with a certificate (unless you`ll get INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error)